# How to deal with sticky tcp packet in go?

Tags: sockets, go, networking, tcp, network-programming

I have a tcp server and a client, the server does the following

```
func providerCallback(conn net.Conn) {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    var err error
    for {
        lenbyte, _ := reader.Peek(4)
        reader.Discard(4)
        slen := int(binary.BigEndian.Uint32(lenbyte))
        data, err = reader.Peek(slen)
        process(data)
        reader.Discard(slen)
    }
}
```

The client seems to send packet faster than process can deal with, therefore I'd like to buffer the requests in bufio and process later.

However, as the size of bufio is fixed(4096, even though I can increase it, it is still fixed), which means I can't manually `Reset` it because there might be a packet cutting of in the end of bufio, as follows

> |normal data... [First 20 bytes of packet P] | [the rest of packet P]
>
> |------------------- size of bufio ------------------|

How can I splice packet that is cut off, and reuse the bufio for later packets?

Comment: If the server does not read the data as fast as the client sends them then the flow control of TCP will automatically slow down the client. There is no need to do this in your application.

Comment: Thanks, but that seems to be OS level, or netstack level. When the client gets automatically slowed down, there are already many packets sent to the server. I think the server still needs to deal with packets that are cut into 2 pieces.

Comment: The is no such thing as "cut into 2 pieces". TCP is a byte stream protocol and not a message based protocol. You should not make any assumptions on packet sizes etc and you should never assume that a single write at the sender results in a single read at the recipient. If you need message syntax then you need to add this to your application protocol, i.e. have the messaged prefixed with the length, have a clear message separater or similar.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I guess I didn't make it clear in text description, but I did use a '4 byte length + content' application protocol in the code. Anyway, peter's answer looks good to me, I'll flag this question as solved. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example,

```
import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/binary"
    "io"
    "net"
)

func providerCallback(conn net.Conn) error {
    rdr := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    data := make([]byte, 0, 4*1024)
    for {
        n, err := io.ReadFull(rdr, data[:4])
        data = data[:n]
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            return err
        }
        dataLen := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(data)
        if uint64(dataLen) > uint64(cap(data)) {
            data = make([]byte, 0, dataLen)
        }
        n, err = io.ReadFull(rdr, data[:dataLen])
        data = data[:n]
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        process(data)
    }
    return nil
}

func process([]byte) {}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems the extra `dataLen` byte array allocation is unavoidable. Is there other way to make bufio work like a circular array and new data is read into the discarded space? I don't find such function in bufio.

Comment: @biggerfish: You don't seem to understand. The code takes care of buffer reuse (like a circular array) with minimal allocations (as in almost none, because of reuse). Your concerns are not justified. Explain, in detail, with examples, why you don't think it works.

Comment: @biggerfish: "it seems the extra dataLen byte array allocation is unavoidable." Clearly, that's false. It's a conditional allocation that's rarely, if ever, made.

Comment: I misunderstood it, you are correct. I'll accept the answer.